# Non-clickable text displayed on file menu

Tags: java, file, menu, jtextfield

I am trying to get some text to display to the menu bar at the top of my application (the empty white space at the end of the row). I could add it as a JMenu with no JMenuItems, I suppose, but I'd really prefer to have it non-clickable. Does anyone know where to start looking to accomplish this? If it isn't possible, is there any way to add a JMenu to the end of the row?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried just adding a JLabel to the JMenuBar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does anyone know where to start looking to accomplish this?

Yes, you would control the positioning with an appropriate [`LayoutManager`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html), and as @MadProgrammer suggested, probably just add a `JLabel` to your `JMenuBar`.

Here is a minimal working example. It might not be exactly what you're looking for, but it does show you where to start looking.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Example {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JMenuBar menubar = new JMenuBar();
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Hello World");
        menubar.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        menubar.add(label, BorderLayout.EAST);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.add(menubar, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(200, 100));
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: This was way easier than expected. Thank you!!